# jQuery auto suggest list freezing chrome, or very slow

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome

I tried to use the script from you tube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqMtE8UO-xw
My auto suggest list is freezing the chrome now it worked before not sure why chrome is freezing now.
I have the below query:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchquery").keyup(function(){
$.get("suggest.php", {searchquery: $(this).val()}, function(data){
$("datalist").empty();
$("datalist").html(data);}); }); });</script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#searchquery2").keyup(function(){
$.get("suggest1.php", {searchquery2: $(this).val()}, function(data){
$("datalist").empty();
$("datalist").html(data); }); });});</script>
```

& I have the following input:

`<th width="170" scope="col"><input type="text" size="25" name="searchquery2" id="searchquery2" placeholder="Business Type" list="datalist1"/><datalist id="datalist1" /> </datalist> </th>
    <th width="170" scope="col"><input type="text" list="myCompanies" size="25" name="searchquery" id="searchquery" placeholder="Suburb, City, or Postcode"/><datalist id="myCompanies" /> </datalist></th>`

Answer (score 0):

Send many ajax request can make browser freeze I suggest you make a timeout for request and just send last value to server. timeout wait if user doesn't type anything then send request. I also suggest to use `input` event instead of `keyup`.
your code should looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchquery").on('input', function() {
        clearTimeout(window.t1);
        window.t1 = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("suggest.php", {
                searchquery: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                $("datalist").empty();
                $("datalist").html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });


    $("#searchquery2").on('input', function() {
        clearTimeout(window.t2);
        window.t2 = setTimeout(function() {
            $.get("suggest1.php", {
                searchquery2: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                $("datalist").empty();
                $("datalist").html(data);
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: HI there thanks for your help. it still freezing check out the site:http://www.ecommercelocal.com.au/

Comment: I have also changed the value 1000 to 100000 and 100 no effect.

Comment: hey dude I check out your site  your problem come from huge data that u load and I suggest you limit result and use above code. You should check the script u use for list view.

Comment: HI there, that data size is fine it worked before perfectly.